# How to make a Custom Button with XML Files?

Tags: android, xml

Since I followed a Video from "Coding in Flow", I did everything (Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1w3y0saKjY)

And of course, I like to add Custom Buttons into my Game. But the Problem is, that the View shows still the standard button or doesn't even like me (that won't even show in preview). And my laptop doesn't have that much space available, then I can't run on AVD Device. And I'll do the first tests on my 25% development completion.

Still, nothing. This is the code (all 5 codes including styles.xml):

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--button_default.xml-->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#2D0D0D"
        android:startColor="#7E0707" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#4E2828" />

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>

<!--button_pressed.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#543838"
        android:startColor="#CA7676" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#4E2828" />

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>

<!--button_disabled.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#989898" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#191919" />

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>

<!--custom_button.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />

</selector>

<!--styles.xml-->
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorControlHighlight</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorControlHighlight</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorControlHighlight</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoStatusBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I hope for any answer. It could be the case of "AndroidX" thing.

Comment: Change: If I change from @android:style into like "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" in styles.xml, then the Custom Button shows. I don't know, what is the issue. And of course, I want those methods still in styles.xml (AppTheme, FullScreen, NoActionBar, NoStatusBar)

Comment: Passed the issue. I did some changing and combining the codes.